# c++ typedef access violation while calling pointer

Tags: c++

I have this code:
(exe)

```
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

class Dummy;
typedef void(Dummy::*Referece)(int i);
typedef void(*InitCall)(void*, Referece);

class Dummy
{
public:
    Dummy(){}
    void callMe(int val)
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, "ok", "ok", 0);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Dummy* obj = new Dummy();

    HMODULE ha= LoadLibraryA("aa.dll");
    InitCall val = (InitCall)GetProcAddress(ha, "Init");

    val(obj, &Dummy::callMe);
}
```

and my dll:
(.h)

```
#pragma once  

#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

class Test;
typedef void (Test::*Reference)(int a);

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    void DLL_EXPORT Init(Test* Object, Reference reference);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

(.cpp)

```
#include "your.h"

void DLL_EXPORT Init(Test * Object, Reference reference)
{
    (Object->*reference)(1);
}
```

I reproduced the system and should be like this cause i can't change code in one side.
Why i get access violation? Calling "val(obj, ref)" i expect a pointer to class + offset to method call.

Comment: Maybe `LoadLibraryA` returned NULL or `GetProcAddress` returned NULL?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes i am on visual studio, and no loadlibraryA load correctly all. With debug i can reach "(Object->*reference)(1);" but calling cause a crash.

Comment: Actually it looks like you are casting a pointer to Init function to a potiner to incompatible type. because signatures of `Referece` in your dll and exe are different. Pointers to non-static member functions (even with same signatures) of different `Dummy` and `Test` classes are not compatible. In general, pointers to c++ functions should not be passes through C-style interface.

Comment: c++ dosn't simply do "object pointer + offsetclass" call? I am tring to tell: trust me, call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer to member is not an "offset into the class." There's no such thing. In *some* cases (such as a pointer to a virtual member function in a class with a simple inheritance hierarchy), its implementation can consist of such an offset (plus potentially a few other bits of data).

However, for a non-virtual function (like in your example), it likely has a plain pointer to function underneath it. Non-virtual functions are not stored in any "table" with "offsets" (there is at least no reason to store them that way), they're most likely implemented as normal bog-standard functions with a mangled name and a prepended prameter.

Pointers to member are a somewhat tricky part of C++, largely due to the fact that there is no obvious mapping to an implementation concept and different compilers can handle them in different ways. Trusting that a `void (Dummy::*)(int)` and `void (Test::*)(int)` are binary compatible is quite fragile.

In general, you cannot expect the binary representation of a pointer to `Dummy::callMe` to be in any way similar to that of a pointer to a member function of `Test`, as it can depend too much on the definitions of `Dummy` and `Test`, and how the compiler implements pointers to member.

To top it off, the way in which Visual Studio's compiler handles pointers to member by default is non-conforming (so, from most perspectives, broken). This default handling is such that to correctly form a pointer to member of a class, the compiler needs to have seen the definition of the class. The reason is that the most general implementation of a pointer to member is quite large (4 native words, I believe), because it has to account for virtual inheritance and such. The most common case of a single-base class with no virtuals can fit in a native word.

Therefore, if you want to reliably use *perfectly standard* C++ constructs like accepting a pointer to member of a class whose definition is not visible at the site, you have to use the compilation flag [`/vmg`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yad46a6z.aspx). With this, the most general representation will always be used.

The default behaviour, `/vmb`, optimises the binary representation (including size!) of `A::*` based on the definition of `A`. It's therefore impossible to create a typedef such as yours with this behaviour in effect.

---

As to what your options are:

- If you absolutely have to pass through a C-style interface, force use of a C-style function as a callback on the side calling the callback, and create a wrapper C-style function on the registering side. Something like this:

  ```
  class Dummy
  {
    void callMe(int) {}
  };

  extern "C" void fw_Dummy_callMe(void *self, int i)
  { static_cast<Dummy*>(self)->callMe(i); }
  ```

  Plus

  ```
  #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C"
  {
  #endif
      void DLL_EXPORT Init(void* Object, void (*reference)(void*, int));

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  }
  #endif
  ```
- If you can have C++ in the interface (that is, the compiler and version will always be the same on both sides of the DLL interface), you can use a pointer to member function provided that:

  1. The two sides will not see *different* definitions of the class. It's fine if one of them only has a non-defining declaration, though. To be 100% C++ conformant, the names of the class should be the same.
  2. You use `/vmg` when building both the DLL and its client.

Comment: How can i create a good pointer to method so? I need for register a callback.

Comment: If you are going to use C-style interface then use a C-style types: a pointer  to void for class instance and a pointer to a regular function.

Comment: I accept your answer cause solved my POC code issue, but actually(i am working with unreal engine and making external dll for it) can't be build with flags.